# Does Eigen have block matrix algorithms for LDL/Cholesky?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

I have a block-symmetric matrix

```
[P A']
[A Q ]
```

and want to do LDL decomposition.

Does Eigen have efficient block matrix algorithms for the decomposition rather than just treating it as a Dense matrix?

Comment: If P, Q, and A are dense, then your matrix is no different than any other symmetric dense matrix.

Comment: It may make sense if `P` or `Q` are shared between different block-matrices (or can be decomposed explicitly, somehow). But you need to work out the block-decomposition yourself in that case.